# Cassandra Cluster Setup getting JMX error

Tags: connection, cassandra, jmx, cluster-computing

I m trying setup a cassandra cluster as a test bed but gave the JMX remote connection error. I seem to found the answer for my error from cassandra FAQ page

---

Nodetool says "Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1" for any remote host. What gives?

Nodetool relies on JMX, which in turn relies on RMI, which in turn sets up it's own listeners and connectors as needed on each end of the exchange. Normally all of this happens behind the scenes transparently, but incorrect name resolution for either the host connecting, or the one being connected to, can result in crossed wires and confusing exceptions.

If you are not using DNS, then make sure that your /etc/hosts files are accurate on both ends. If that fails try passing the -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$IP option to the JVM at startup (where $IP is the address of the interface you can reach from the remote machine).

---

But can somebody help me on how to do -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$IP
Or what to add is hosts file, i know that in hosts normally we add "IP Alias", but whose ip and alias.

I dont know much java or either linux

I m currently working on ubuntu v10.04 and cassandra v0.74

Sudesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For JMX you need to enable JMX-remoting:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
```

Depending on from where you want to access the jmx-server, you also need to specify a port:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345
```

and set or disable passwords.

Have a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html for more details.

Comment: thanks for your reply, 
I went through the url you gave and i executed the code below 
`code`java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8080 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false `code`
But the above command did not execute, is my command wrong

Comment: @Sudesh Did you add the first option -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote

Comment: I executed this code  

`code`
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8080 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
`code`

and got output  

`code`
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
`code`

I dont know what i m doing wrong

Comment: @Sudesh: You need to add those switches in addition to what have been there before. If Cassandra start scripts have the concept of JAVA_OPTS env variable, then add them there.

Comment: Thanks Heiko you showed the way, i trying to execute these commands in terminal rather i should have defined them in their respective configuration files. I was not needed to add the above java commands as it was already there. For cassandra nodetools to work i have open bin/nodetool in a editer and add -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$IP at the end where people can see java commands, this did the trick. Heiko thanks again for showing the way